# How to require a parameter be of two types when passed to a method in Java

Tags: java

In one class, I have to call a constructor of another class that needs two parameters, a `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver` and a `ContextWrapper`. The problem is they're both `this`.

Note: `ContextWrapper` is a framework class that I have no control over (`android.content.ContextWrapper`, actually). My class (an Android `Activity`) is-a `ContextWrapper` already, and I want to mix-in a little `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`ness to it.

Also note, my class is one of several classes that all inherit from `ContextWrapper`, so combining `ContextWrapper` and `IHelloServiceConnectionObserer` won't work.

I could do this:

```
HelloServiceConnection svc = HelloServiceConnection(this,this);
```

calls

```
public HelloServiceConnection(IHelloServiceConnectionObserver observer, ContextWrapper contextWrapper){
    this.observer = observer;
    this.contextWrapper = contextWrapper;
}
```

But that looks silly. Or I could do this:

```
HelloServiceConnection svc = HelloServiceConnection(this);
```

calls

```
public HelloServiceConnection(IHelloServiceConnectionObserver observer){
    this.observer = observer;
    this.contextWrapper = (ContextWrapper) observer;
}
```

But now I move a nice compile time error to a runtime error.

What's the best practice here?

EDIT: Well, I can't say it's a "best practice", but for my special set of circumstances, Jon Skeet has the right answer.  Here's what the code ends up looking like:

```
helloServiceConnection = HelloServiceConnection.create(this);
```

calls

```
public static <T extends ContextWrapper & IHelloServiceConnectionObserver> HelloServiceConnection create(T value){
    return new HelloServiceConnection(value, value);
}
```

which in turn calls

```
private HelloServiceConnection(IHelloServiceConnectionObserver observer, ContextWrapper contextWrapper){
    this.observer = observer;
    this.contextWrapper = contextWrapper;
}
```

So let me give a bit more context as to why this is the right answer for this special situation.  Since `ContextWrapper` is part of a framework that I don't control, I can't change it. Because it's also an ancestor of several classes, any one of which I might want to use `HelloServiceConnection` in, it doesn't really make sense to extend all the decendants of `ContextWrapper` to add in `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`.

So I thought I was left will little choice but the `this,this` idom. Jon's answer, once I understood it, saves the day!

Thanks, Jon -- and thanks to all who participated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *could* make the call generic:

```
public <T extends ContextWrapper & IHelloServiceConnectionObserver> void method
    (T item)
```

and let type inference sort it out. It's not terribly pleasant though.

EDIT: It looks like you're trying to use a constructor, which is going to make it harder. You can use a static method to create the instance though:

```
public static <T extends ContextWrapper & IHelloServiceConnectionObserver>
    HelloServiceConnection createConnection(T value)
{
    return new HelloServiceConnection(value, value);
}

private HelloServiceConnection(ContextWrapper wrapper,
                               IHelloServiceConnectionObserver observer)
{
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
    this.observer = observer;
}
```

Okay, so the constructor and the type itself will end up with two separate fields - but we know that they will both refer to the same object. You could even assert that in the constructor if you like.

As others have said though, it's worth considering whether you really, really need this coupling. What bad things would happen if the wrapper and the observer weren't the same object?

Comment: Agreed. The method doesn't know, or want to know, that the two interfaces are implemented by the same instance. Your embarrassment at writing `this, this` will quickly pass.

Comment: In the context of my app, I fully expect that they will always be the same object and don't mind encoding that into the interface.

Comment: If they'll always be the same object then you should declare a new type that extends/implements both of them, and use that type in your methods/constructors.

Comment: @ide -- can't combine because `ContextWrapper` is high up in a framework hierarchy and I actually instantiate lower level classes. I added a note to the question to explain this.

Comment: @Jon -- You answered very early, before I had time to fix my question (accidentally posted it too early), so I don't actually understand your answer, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jon -- because of the way the app works, they will always be the same object. I'd combine them, but one is a framework object that's high  up in the hierarchy -- so combination makes little sense. Your edited answer is perfect, however and I've updated the question with your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a point of the fact that the object has the type ContextWrapper AND implements the interface then you could cast it in the method call?

```
method((ContextWrapper)this, (IHelloServiceConnectionHelper)this)
```

The casts are obviously redundant but it makes your point more explicit.

Comment: Problem here is I still end up with runtime type checking instead of compile time type checking.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada - no. There's no runtime checking here.  The compiler should realizes that the typecasts are redundant and doesn't generate bytecodes to do it.  (Or if for some reason it does, the runtime check will always succeed.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should stay with your current design, or have `ContextWrapper` extend `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`. Your argument for merging the two is that `new HelloServiceConnection(this, this)` looks awkward. But why is this scenario even present?

It's because you just so happen to have an object that is both a `ContextWrapper` and `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`. If they should always be together (which you're forcing on the programmer by merging the two constructor parameters together), then make one type extend the other. Or, have `HelloServiceConnection` take one parameter that is whatever type `this` is.

If they should be separate, then your current code is fine. Or, instead of having your current class (the type of `this`) extend/implement both `ContextWrapper` and `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`, you could have it extend/implement only one of them and have a member variable that points to an instance of the other. Remember, when in doubt, [use composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Comment: Thanks -- I added a Note that explains that `ContentWrapper` is part of the Android framework, so I can't have it extend `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`.

Comment: Hmm. Unless you strongly feel that your `Activity` absolutely is an `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`, I would not implement that interface, and instead add a member variable that is an `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`. What's important to note is that your `HelloServiceConnection` constructor wants an `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver` and `ContextWrapper` (which is the basis of this question), and a very clear way of stating that is with two parameters of those types, which you already have. It just so happens that your `Activity` is both of those.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be afraid to write this code:

```
IHelloServiceConnectionObserver observer = this;
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = this;
HelloServiceConnection svc = new HelloServiceConnection(observer, contextWrapper);
```

But in fact, I would reconsider having the `this`'s class be both a `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver` *and* a `ContextWrapper`.

Wherever possible, I have my classes either extend just 1 class, or implement just 1 interface.  I like the clarity and separation afforded by that approach.  This philosophy prefers a 'has-a' relationship instead of an 'is-a' relationship.  Inner member classes in Java make a "one inheritance per class" approach fairly practical.

Comment: I agree with the has-a over is-a, but is-a relationships, especially with interfaces really help to de-couple code. Because my class implements `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver`, the `HelloServiceConnection` can call back into it without knowing what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you do this:

> HelloServiceConnection svc =
>   HelloServiceConnection((**IHelloServiceConnectionObserver**)this,(**ContextWrapper**)this);

Same thing as you tried before, but more verbose!

Comment: I do not think explicit casting to a superclass is ever a good idea.

Comment: As i mentioned, it's for verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

Another (not pleasant IMO) solution would be to create an interface `Combined` that extends your `IHelloServiceConnectionObserver` and `ContextWrapper` interfaces, change the class of `this` to implement `ICombined`, and change `HelloServiceConnection` to take a single argument of type `ICombined`.

Comment: That almost sounds perfect, except for one thing not stated in the question. There are several other framework classes that inherit from `ContextWrapper`, any of which could use a `HelloServiceConnection`. To implement your approach I'd have to create several `Combined` classes (`CombinedActivity`, `CombinedApplication`) which leaves the whole system fragile. Not pleasant -- agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Conceptually, it declares a generic type `Combined` which creates `HelloServiceConnection` objects using themselves as both the observer and and context wrapper.

```
class ContextWrapper {}

interface IHelloServiceConnectionObserver {}

class HelloServiceConnection
{
    HelloServiceConnection(ContextWrapper cw, IHelloServiceConnectionObserver o)
    { 
        System.out.println("HelloServiceConnection(" + cw + " ," + o + ")");
    }
}

abstract class Combined<T> extends ContextWrapper
        implements IHelloServiceConnectionObserver
{
    public HelloServiceConnection svc()
    {
        return new HelloServiceConnection(this, this);
    }
}

class MyClass extends Combined<MyClass>
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(mc);
        mc.svc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops. Looks like that is same as Jon Skeet's approach.